# Topologies making a class of functions continuous

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let $X:=\{f: \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}\}$ be a class of *total* functions on $\mathbb{C}$ closed under composition, addition, multiplication, and scalar multiplication.  Does there exist a topology on $\mathbb{C}$ making these functions and only these functions continuous?

If it's not true in general (it probably isn't), are there any interesting known cases where it is true?

Note: I emphasize *total* functions because we want them to be everywhere defined.  This avoids functions with bad singularities.

Edit: Obviously, continuous functions in the standard topology fit this bill, but this is tautological and not in the spirit of the problem.

Edit 2: Apparently the way I asked this question made it seem like I was looking for an answer to the "general case" which seems pretty untrue although I haven't actually worked it out.  Rather, the real question was interesting cases where it is true.

Comment: Do you want the same topology at both ends, or just on the domain side?

Comment: What if you take X to be the set of polynomial functions?  Then the question asks whether or not there is a larger class of functions (with the closure properties you mention) which is continuous with respect to the Zariski (= cofinite, here) topology.  There are lots of non-polynomial Zariski-continuous functions: e.g., note that pulling back the cofinite topology by any permutation of C gives the cofinite topology.  Have you tried working this out?  

Comment: @FGD: If the topology is not the same on both sides, then the problem is pretty trivial.

Comment: If X does not contain the identity function, then X is a counterexample.  For example, the set of constant functions is a counterexample.  (Or do you interpret "closed under composition" as including 0-fold compositions, which would give you the identity for free?)

Comment: @Pete: It's obviously false in general. I was really wondering about any interesting cases where it is true. I just stated it the way I did because it's more interesting when stated that way.  

Comment: @Bjorn, I'm not really looking for counterexamples, I'm looking for examples.  

Comment: @Harry: I am suggesting an answer to the question posed in the first paragraph, or rather suggesting a strategy for you to answer the question yourself.  Contrary to your latest remark, it doesn't sound to me like you have worked through a counterexample. I encourage you to do this.

Comment: Example machine: Take X to be the set of all continuous function for a topology on C with respect to which addition and multiplication are continuous...

Comment: OK, here are 2^{2^{\aleph_0}} examples: Let s be any field automorphism of C, and consider {s \circ f \circ s^{-1} : f is continuous in the usual sense}!

Comment: Could you guys close this?  I know at least Joel and Pete can vote to close.

Comment: I voted to close as well.

Comment: Well, I did what you asked, but actually, I find it interesting.

Comment: I guess I didn't put enough thought into the question, as Pete revealed to me via the Socratic method.

Comment: @fpqc: I too did what you asked, but I agree with Joel that there is something interesting here.  Maybe it could be reworded somehow to encourage the kind of answers you are hoping for.

Comment: Well, we can always reopen it later.  I'd rather have some time to think about it.

Comment: I voted to re-open, as a way to encourage you to edit the question. I continue to think that there is something interesting here.


Comment: @Joel: When I figure out how to edit the question to make it better, I'm just going to ask it as a new question.  

Comment: I've got a lot of work and an exam this week, so if you can think of an interesting way to ask it, feel free to re-ask it yourself in another question.  I say this mainly because I don't know how to fix the question (although admittedly I haven't given it much thought).  

Comment: @JDH: We are all finding our way in this new social environment, so what I say is tentative, but: it seems to me that if the questioner wants a question to be closed, it should be -- and stay -- closed.  I think Harry is right when he says that anyone who is interested in the question can easily ask a new (and, one hopes, improved) version of the question.  Please go ahead and ask a new question if you like: the topic seems interesting to me too.

Answer (score 2):

If X is the set of all functions, then it has your closure properties, and the indiscrete topology {emptyset, C} makes exactly those functions continuous.